# hide all the div by passing id value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am passing a value by id in javascript where it have to hide the li if it gets the id but the issue is it only hide the first li second li is still shown

```js
$(function() {
  $("#0").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="0" class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
    <span>Header Options<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a href="addlogo.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="addmenu.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add Main Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="addslider.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add slider img</a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
<li id="0" class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
    <span>Home Content<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a href="home_content.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add 
                   Content</a></li>



  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: use class to hide

Comment: 'Id's are unique, use class instead.

Comment: You can have one unique ID per element. You can't more than one element with same ID.

Comment: but i have to hide all the li which have the id 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this then.

```js
$(function() {
  $("li").each(function(index, item) {
    var li = $(item);
    if(li.attr('id') == "0")
      li.hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="0" class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
    <span>Header Options<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a href="addlogo.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="addmenu.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add Main Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="addslider.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add slider img</a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
<li id="0" class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
    <span>Home Content<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a href="home_content.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add 
                   Content</a></li>



  </ul>
</li>
```

## But that's not how to use IDs

Way better idea would be to use `data` attribute. Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("li[data-id='0']").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-id="0" class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
    <span>Header Options<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a href="addlogo.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="addmenu.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add Main Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="addslider.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add slider img</a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
<li data-id="0" class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
    <span>Home Content<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a href="home_content.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add 
                   Content</a></li>



  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Id's are unique per element. Try using classes when to hide multiple html elements. Your code will look like this, **HTML**:

```
<li class="treeview 0">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
                <span>Header Options<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="addlogo.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add logo</a></li>
                <li><a href="addmenu.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add Main Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="addslider.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add slider img</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>   
            <li class="treeview 0">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
                <span>Home Content<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="home_content.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add 
               Content</a></li>



                </ul>
            </li>
```

**JS**:

```
$(function() {
  $(".0").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `id` attribute with the same value more than one time. instead you can use `class` attribute.

**Bad Code:**

```
<div id="my-div">Hello, World A</div>
<div id="my-div">Hello, World B</div>
```

**Good Code:**

```
<div class="my-div">Hello, World A</div>
<div class="my-div">Hello, World B</div>
```

**Also:** It's not good to start `id` or `class` value with a number.

**Then for your case**

```js
$('.my-div').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-div">Hello, World A</div>
<div class="my-div">Hello, World B</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class that is common to all elements you need to hide, like this:

```js
function hideLi() {
  $(".treeview").hide();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="0" class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
    <span>Header Options<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a href="addlogo.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add logo</a></li>
    <li><a href="addmenu.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add Main Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="addslider.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add slider img</a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
<li id="0" class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
    <span>Home Content<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a href="home_content.php"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Add 
                   Content</a></li>



  </ul>
</li>
<button onMouseUp="hideLi()">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the others, don't use duplicate ID's!

But if there's no other way round, get all `LI` elements, then filter the ones with `#0` and hide those:

```
$(function() {
  $("li").filter("#0").hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L5eyg5fp/

`$("li").attr("id","0").hide();` would also work. Or a [DOM traversal method](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) that includes the current element - such as `closest()` - can be used in this case (just make sure you know what such method does).